# loop through a filter call in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, tidy

I have a dataframe of genetic data called 'windows'

```
glimpse(windows)
Rows: 3,000
Columns: 5
$ chrpos       <chr> "1:104159999-104168402", "1:104159999-104168402", "1:104159999-104168402"
$ target       <chr> "AMY2A", "CFD13", "PUTA"
$ name         <chr> "rs5753", "rs70530", "rs21111"
$ chr          <chr> "1", "1", "1"
$ pos          <int> 104560629, 104562750, 104557705
```

I want to make them in to separate dataframes by the row in the column 'target'

```
AMY2A<- filter(windows, target == 'AMY2A')
write.table("am2ya.txt", header=T)
```

Which works fine, but is laborious doing for each element row of 'target'

But how do I loop through all of these, and then save them out as text files, in one go?

```
list <- windows$target
for(i in list)
df.list[[i]]<-filter(windows, target == list[[i]])
```

Which gives the error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = target == list[[i]]`.
Caused by error in `list[[i]]`:
! subscript out of bounds
```

And when I google saving out multiple txt files, it just comes up how to read in multiple text files.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably something like:

```r
lst <- windows$target

for(i in seq_along(lst)){
  dat <- filter(windows, target == lst[[i]])
  write.table(dat, paste0(tolower(lst[[i]]), ".txt"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, using the tidyverse, something like

```
windows %>% 
  group_by(target) %>% 
  group_walk(
    function(.x, .y) {
      write.table(.x, paste0(tolower(.y$target[1]), ".txt"))
    },
    .keep=TRUE
  )
```

[Untested code, since your question is not reproducible.]

the `.keep=TRUE` keeps the `target` column in the text file.  If that's unnecessary, feel free to delete it.  Details are in the online doc.

Comment: Random question. Would `cur_group()` work in the `write.table` function instead of `.y$target[1]`? I couldn't test since there is no data in the question. Also, what is the benefit of `group_walk` opposed to say `group_split` and `map`?  PS. Thanks for teaching me a new function.

Comment: `cur_group()` won't work here: it has to be used inside a `dplyr` verb.  (But I had to check, thanks for asking.)  `group_split` would work as well, I think.  The main difference is that using `group_split` followed by `map` would return a list.  `group_walk` is called for its side effects and returns its input, invisibly.  In this particular case, that seems neater and more appropriate, IMHO.  But it's all a matter of style...  [See also `group_map()` and `group_modify()`.]